# Debug MarkLogic Search Query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am Executing Following Java Code to Perform my Search Operation.

```
        QueryManager queryManager = client.newQueryManager();
        StructuredQueryBuilder builder = queryManager.newStructuredQueryBuilder();
        StructuredQueryDefinition definition = builder.and(
            builder.value(builder.element("filterField"), "abc"),
            builder.range(builder.element("filterName"), "xs:string", Operator.EQ, "newfilter")
            );
        definition.setCollections(BaseDataConstants.FILTER_COLLECTIONS);

        SearchHandle searchHandle = new SearchHandle();
        queryManager.search(definition, searchHandle);
```

**Requirement** : I want to Print the Actual Search query fired against ML for Above java Code.

I don't know whether this is right question or not...but Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

To see the Search API query sent by the client, call the serialize() method, as in:

```
System.out.println(definition.serialize());
```

For more, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryDefinition.html#serialize--

You can see the cts:query being executed by setting the `return-query` query option to true.  For more information, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_76144

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_60243

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/io/SearchHandle.html#getReports--

Hoping that helps,